# find $f(n)$ for recurrence $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\mathcal{O}(n\log{n})=\Theta(f(n))$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursion

> We have recurrence $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\mathcal{O}(n\log{n})$ and
> assume $T(1)$ is a constant. Find asymptotically tight bounds
> $\Theta(f(n))$ for $T(n)$.

There's something that confuses me. We know $\{n\log{n}, n, \sqrt{n}\}\subset \mathcal{O}(n\log{n})$. So with Master Theorem applied:

- if $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+n\log{n}$, then $T(n)=\Theta(n\log^2{n})$
- if $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+n$, then $T(n)=\Theta(n\log{n})$
- if $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\sqrt{n}$, then $T(n)=\Theta(\sqrt{n})$

If its asymptotically tight bounds varies, then how can we provide a asymptotically tight bounds for $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\mathcal{O}(n\log{n})$? If we can, how? Can we prove it using induction?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/162604/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4793413/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).